# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am trying to create a new React app using Vite. What I have done so far is run the command `npm create vite@latest`. I was able to create the app, run npm install, npm run dev to run it on localhost. But when I opened console, there is an error message and I could not find any solution on the Internet to fix it.
Here is the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. 
at it (blur.js:42:3933)
    at s.useContext (blur.js:42:5675)
    at cr (blur.js:57:31858)
    at blur.js:61:494
    at blur.js:126:5191
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at I (blur.js:126:4967)
```

I created the app with Git Bash, the error showed up. Then I tried with Windows PowerShell, it was the same. Even though I did not make any changes in the code, the error showed up right after I run "npm run dev"

Here is the packages I have:

```
{
    "name": "sikka-patient-portal",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
        "redux": "^4.2.1",
        "sass": "^1.58.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.1.0"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

Does any one have a solution? Much appreciate it!

I tried to create the app with different terminal (git bash, windows powershell) as well as looked for the solution online but could not find any.

Comment: I also just got this recently appearing in dev tools console both locally and on my development build site, even going back to an old branch where it definitely wasn't appearing, it now is, although I'm using `webpack` and not `vite.

Comment: check your browser extensions. if there is any Loom's extension, disable it. Then Run again.

Answer (score 31):

I got it today too... From my understanding, it seems that it's not linked to your/our codebase. On my side, it seems to be linked to a Chrome Extension (Loom). After I disabled it, this error disappears

Comment: I second that. You can confirm this if you run it in incognito - no plugins there.

Comment: Yep, the Loom extension was also the culprit for me. Glad I didn't need to go down my giant list of extensions 

Comment: yes it was Loom extension that caused the issue

Answer (score 1):

I got this error also. On my side , it seems you are using any extension or plugins in your browser. Disable it and check again. you can test that Running it in incognito also.

Comment: Yes it was it. I had to remove the Loom extension. But I heard that Vite will give errors sometimes but does not state what exactly is wrong with the code so I switched back to `create-react-app`.